# google home rest call to private device

Tags: api, rest, webhooks, actions-on-google, google-home

I've a google home mini device (with google home app then), and I've another device on the same network that I would like to post a simple api rest call to.

Is there any way to do so using google mini/home?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Actions on Google platform runs on the server using publicly accessible URLs. You can build an Action that uses a webhook to [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) data from a public URL. However, if the API is only accessible on the local network, this is not possible. You'd need some way to expose your private device API to the public Internet in order to call it.